# Find $f$ that solves the following optimization problem: $\min_{f} \frac{f(x, y)}{f(y, x) \times x}$, where $x$, $y$ are constant real numbers.

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, functional-equations

I'm trying to find an $f$ that solves the following optimization problem:

$\min_{f} \frac{f(x, y)}{f(y, x) \times x}$, where $x$, $y$ are constant positive real numbers.

subject to  $f$: $\mathbb{{R}^+}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$

There are no other restrictions on $f$. I've gotten to this problem by modelling an engineering problem, so I may be able to place additional restrictions on $f$ if it will help lead to a solution. I'd really like to know if a general solution exists, though. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in a possible direction to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are fixed then the minimum does not exist. Suppose that $x>0$. I can always choose $f(y,x)<0$ and assign some arbitrarily large value to $f(x,y)$. I can do the reverse if $x<0$.

Comment: I completely spaced out on this when posting, my apologies - this was a key piece of information. $f$ should be from $\mathbb{{R}^+}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$. I've edited the question.

Comment: Your optimisation problem is equivalent to $\min_{a,b} \, \frac{a}{b}$ subject to $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$, where these inequalities are strict if $f$ must be strictly positive. If the inequalities are weak, the minimum is $0$. Otherwise, it does not exist, for reasons similar to my previous comment.